How is the dialog template replaced?
The dialog for a search form is triggered when:

The Menu Link attributes module is installed

The attributes are configured on /admin/config/menu_link_attributes/config
attributes:
  container_class:
    label: 'Container class'
    description: 'Class for wrapping the element'
  data-dialog-type:
    label: Dialog
    description: 'Specify a dialog. Usually "modal"'
  data-dialog-options:
    label: 'Dialog Options'
    description: 'Set dialog options. width=80vw'




I initialized the modal with Twig debugging on. There are no suggestions for the dialog itself.

The Bulma modal component template is the following.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to replace the drupal modal output code with this. I am guessing that example-modal.html.twig would become modal.html.twig in my custom theme. It doesn't look like it will work from the suggestions.
Do I have to therefore implement a hook to add this theme to the form element?
Is there a standard pattern for using Drupal components?
